# std::map.find() stopping at first element?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a std::map that contains 3 elements, and I'm trying to to see if a key exists in the map. I have put the map through the debugger, and it contains all 3 elements added to it. When using find it stops after the first element and immediatley returns map.end()... I even made sure to override the operator< in the key. Anyone have a clue why find is stopping after the first key?

Here is the operator< for the key:

```
bool MyClass::operator<(const MyClass& myClass) const
{
    bool aIsEqual = a == myClass.a || a == "0" || myClass.a == "0";
    bool bIsEqual = b == myClass.b || b == "0" || myClass.b == "0";
    bool cIsEqual = c == myClass.c || c == "0" || myClass.c == "0";

    return !aIsEqual || !bIsEqual || !cIsEqual;
}
```

Comment: There are requirements on `operator<`, such as transitivity and [anti-reflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation).  You aren't meeting them.

Comment: In order to better analyse your problem, could you please post the code of the entire class 'MyClass' as well as the code starting at which you create the map, add items to the map, and at which you query, please? Also note, Ben Voigt's comment.

Comment: `operator<` should create an order. It seems you write something like `operator !=` currently.

Comment: Here are the rules you must follow: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at these.

Comment: Also please tell us which version of C++ you are using because my answer will change depending on which version.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is one of the *associative containers* as defined in section 23.2.4 of the standard.
There are resctrictions you have to keep in mind while implementing the `operator<` or `Compare` object for these containers:

> 2. Each associative container is parameterized on `Key` and an ordering relation `Compare` that induces a strict weak ordering ( 25.4 ) on
>      elements of `Key`. *(...)*
> 3. The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the
>      equivalence relation imposed by  the comparison and not the operator==
>      on keys. That is, two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be
>      equivalent if for the comparison object `comp`, `comp(k1, k2) == false
>      && comp(k2, k1) == false`. For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the same
>      container, calling `comp(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value.

In your case you failed to meet these conditions (e.g. the ordering), hence the "bad" behaviour of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your `a`, `b,` and `c` members actually represent, I can only guess, but I would think your operator should probably look something more like this instead:

```
bool MyClass::operator<(const MyClass& myClass) const
{
    if ((a < myClass.a) || ((a == "0") && (myClass.a != "0")))
        return true;

    if (a == myClass.a)
    {
        if ((b < myClass.b) || ((b == "0") && (myClass.b != "0")))
            return true;

        if (b == myClass.b)
            return ((c < myClass.c) || ((c == "0") && (myClass.c != "0")));
    }

    return false;
}
```